# How to setup Angular example app in jsFiddle?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsfiddle

So I'm trying to setup my [Angular app example in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/scx479rw/) to get help on another bug, however I'm getting a new bug:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/scx479rw/

Added example in Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/yYQHbcatHOu5myL4MXZM?p=preview
I wasn't able to add `ng-app="portal"` to the html tag because jsFiddle generates it's own html tag in the output, so I put `ng-app` in my first div, could that be the problem?

**"Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'portal' is not available!**

HTML

```
 <div class="nav"
     ng-app="portal"
     ng-controller="NavController as nav">
```

Angular

```
var app = angular.module('portal');

// Controller for Nav
app.controller('NavController', function() {
    ....
```

If it can't find portal because of that issue, how would you setup an Angular app in jsFiddle?

Comment: Read the whole error message, please: `Module 'portal' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

Comment: I personally always have issues getting angular to play nice in a JSFiddle - so tend to use http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue - it also updates as soon as you make changes, rather than having to press run. Food for thought...

Comment: @Blackhole well obviously you can see for yourself that I did not misspell 'portal' try again...

Comment: By "whole error message", I mean "also the last sentence"… And by the way, use the option "No wrap - in <head>" in JSFiddle.

Comment: @Darren thanks! I'm trying to setup my example app here now: http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/scx479rw/ however looks like the style isn't working

Comment: @LeonGaban, I usually just go to AngularJS official site and open up one of their Plunkers and strip it down. Unless you're adamant on using jsfiddle over plunker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see here 
http://jsfiddle.net/dvtofn6L/1/

You missed few bits 
1:

```
var app = angular.module('portal', []);
```

2.

```
app.controller('SubNavController', function ($scope) {})
```

3. Reference to jquery (you can add that in external source tab)

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js